# read elements with same name but different attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to print out the phone numbers of the people in my XML file.

These are the elements that i want to print out

```
<telefon typ="home">11111111</telefon>
<telefon typ="work">23232323</telefon>
<telefon typ="cell">95959595</telefon>
```

But I only manage to print out one of them. Of course the first one.

This is my XSL file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h1>Lista över <xsl:value-of select="count(/*/*/namn)"/> personer</h1><br />
<xsl:for-each select="//person[namn]" >
<h2>Person
<xsl:value-of select="position()" />
<xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="namn" /></h2>
<h3>Kontaktuppgifter: </h3>
Gata: <xsl:value-of select="adress/gata" />
<br />
Postnr: <xsl:value-of select="adress/postnr" />
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="adress/postort" />
<br />
<br />
<xsl:element name="telefon">
<xsl:value-of select="telefon/@typ" /> 
<xsl:text>: </xsl:text> 
<xsl:value-of select="telefon" />
</xsl:element>
<hr />
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I change the last element to something like this
`<xsl:value-of select="." />` It  prints out all of the elements, but of course the whole tree structure.

I didn't really wanted to ask here and manage to fix it by my self but after a couple of hours I'm throwing the towel.

Comment: So what exactly do you want the output to be?

Comment: And is that really the input? I suspect you're leaving out some context.

Comment: So it output the type also.
home:11111111
work:23232323
cell:95959595

Comment: @Iwburk I'll edit and show my whole code. But Im quite ashame of =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a loop around all of the `<telefon>` data elements. The code would look something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="telefon" >
    <xsl:value-of select="@typ" /> 
    <xsl:text>: </xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: oh my..! of course. Don't know why I'm having such a trouble remember what I read. need to start writing notes and test my self, instead of wasting time trying to invent something new :)

Thank you and thank you all on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your context (where you are "standing" in the node tree when this piece if XSLT is executing) is the parent of the `<telefon>` elements.

In your current code, when you use `<xsl:value-of select="telefon/@typ"/>` the XPath will match all three of the typ attributes, but `<xsl:value-of>` will return the first one that it encounters.

When you use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`, you are getting the calculated string-value of the current node (the parent of the `<telefon>` elements), which will be the concatenation of all the `text()` nodes.

You will want something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

<!--assuming that the document element is the parent element of the telefon elements -->
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="telefon"/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="telefon">
        <!--xsl:copy will do what xsl:element name="telefon" was doing-->
        <xsl:copy>
            <!--select this telefon element's typ attribute value-->
            <xsl:value-of select="@typ"/>
            <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
            <!--now that the context is the telefon element, value of . will yield expected result -->
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```